# Newly-upgraded Mavericks machine hangs on startup

Tags: macos, startup, performance

I just upgraded to Mavericks on my 2.8 quad desktop, and now it won't fully boot.  It gets to the Apple logo, then hangs. I tried safe boot but got the same result.  Where to next?

Answer (score 2):

1) You have a backup, right?

2) Boot into the recovery partition: hold option before apple logo appears, select recovery hd.

3) Run disk utiity form the recovery hd, select your boot partition (usually macintosh hd), and hit verify disk. It will probably find errors on the partition.

4) If disk utility finds errors, hit "repair disk" in disk utility. If it succeeds, you should be able to boot normally. If it fails, reformat and reinstall.

If disk utility doesn't find errors... try reinstalling without reformatting.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your assistance.

I have time machine as my back up.  Is that going to be useful or should I hang my head in shame?

Disc utility says the HD appears ok but I paused before electing to back up from the time machine external disk because it talks about reformatting the HD as part of the back up/recovery process.  I wanted to check with the experts first.